# Managed Package Installs

Tags: managed-package, appexchange

Is there a way I can get a report from the App Exchange that shows who all has installed my app?  I see that there is a report in app exchange that shows the number of installs, but I would like to know what version of my app and who has installed it if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using License Management App? This gives developers an ability to track how many customers have installed your app. Here is the [link](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/lma/Content/lma_overview.htm).